# Interpreting $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: extension-field, cauchy-sequences

My apologies if this question is somewhat vague or too broad.

Analytically, the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is no trivial fact. It requires some kind of completion of the rational numbers, e.g. by adjoining the limit of some Cauchy sequence of rational numbers or taking appropriate Dedekind cuts.

Algebraically, one need not accept the existence of limits of Cauchy sequences to talk about $\sqrt{2}$. Instead we talk about adjoining to the rationals the solutions to the polynomial $x^2-2$. Then we can discuss "irrational" numbers in terms of field extensions.

My question is, in what sense are these two points of view equivalent? In both cases we are completing the rational numbers by adjoining extra elements to them, but can one go from one interpretation to another without loss of information? Does every irrational limit of a Cauchy sequence of rationals correspond to a field extension of the rationals, and vice versa?

Comment: Not all real numbers are roots of polynomials.

Comment: You can relate the solution of a polynomial to a cauchy sequence through Newton's method

Comment: In fact, since there are countably many polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$, and each of these only has finitely many roots, there are only countably many such roots (i.e., algebraic numbers) in all.

Comment: In one case you're actually completing $\Bbb Q$ with respect to its metric, and in the other you're algebraically closing $\Bbb Q$ with respect to field extensions of finite degree over it.

Comment: These points of view are not equivalent. The real numbers are bigger than the (real) algebraic numbers.